# Kendo UI Dropdown Action Links

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm trying to add dropdown to the 4th col but not sure how to do that. I want to do the following:

- Add Action dropdown with Delete, Update, Edit options
- When I click on delete, update or edit I want to call some function

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/JQPurfect/5wZ3R/1/

```
{field: 'Title', filterable: { ui: titleFilter }},
{field: 'City', title: 'City', filterable: { ui: cityFilter }},
{field: 'FirstName', title: 'Action', filterable: { ui: nameFilter }} //This is where I want the dropdown.
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to use a client template for each row? :) That usually works good for when you want custom functionality on the rows :)

Comment: Can you share any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the kendo template to place the select in the 4th col

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="selectTemplate">
  <select class='action' data-id="#=data.id#" >
                        <option value="">Select an action</option>
                        <option value="Edit">Edit</option>
                        <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
                    </select>
    </script>
```

and use this template in that col

```
{field: '', title: 'Action', filterable: { ui: nameFilter },template : $('#selectTemplate').html()}
```

and wired the change event to all the select elements

```
$('#grid').on('change','.action',function(){
                     alert($(this).val());
 });
```

here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cT3YK/2/